# Does all persistent actors reside in-memory?

Tags: akka, akka-persistence

I have an order represented by a persistent Order Actor in Akka (say persisted in Cassandra)

I have numerous orders in my system.

At any point of time, does all the Order Actors reside in-memory ? or would some** of the order actors be retrieved from cassandra, as needed ?
How does it internally work ?

*those order Entities that are rarely needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends on your code. A persistent actor state is recovered when the actor is started and will stay in memory until you stop the actor.

It’s up to you to stop the actors you don’t need if you want to release the memory they’re consuming.